# Import net.liftweb.widgets is ignored and pom has widgets dependency BUT javax.mail 1.4.5 version issue

Tags: scala, maven, lift

So, I can't import the widgets module because my pom seems to, upon having a dependency to the widget repo, bug out on a versioning issue javax

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Couldn't find a version in [1.4.5-rc1] to match range [1.4,1.4.3)
  javax.mail:mail:jar:null

Comment: You should post your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this repo to your pom http://download.java.net/maven/2/